# discovering Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, tangent-line, rolles-theorem, mean-value-theorem

mean value theorem for single variable function is very easy and intuitive once you "see" the formula.

Actually, My question, slightly weird but helpful, is that How does someone come up with this formula in the first place?

Because, every time I refer a book or video for proof, I always see that we introduce a new function as the difference between given function and the equation of line passing through the endpoints of the interval.

How would someone even think of that function in the first place?

P.S This question does not hinder the proof but it always circulates the thought that "How someone would have think of that first?"

Comment: Mean value theorem is just Rolle's theorem with axes rotated a bit. Hence if one is able to visualize Rolle's theorem it's not difficult to get to mean value theorem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh do you have some references that explain the “rotated axes” concept in a bit more detail? I’d be interested.

Comment: @insipidintegrator: well mean value theorem says that under right conditions (continuity, differentiability) given a chord to a curve we can always find a tangent parallel to it. For Rolle's the chord is parallel to x-axis. But this is not necessary as far as geometry is concerned.

Comment: I don't really know about "rotated axes" thing. can you please share how it works?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, surely I understood what you are trying to say. But assume that you don't know about rolle's theorem at all. Then how can you come up with this idea and what type of proof will you provide without help of Rolle's theorem?

Comment: Rolle's theorem is a very simple, almost 'obvious' result and many beginning students implicitly accept it before they've even *heard* of real analysis, or what 'Rolle's theorem' even is... it would be difficult and in my opinion not worthwhile to worry about proving the MVT without Rolle. Rolle's theorem allows a nice generalisation to Cauchy's mean value theorem too!

Comment: @FShrike yeah true, but sometimes the books say that rolle's theorem is the special form of MVT; and for proving MVT, Rolle's theorem is a must. then why they call it as a special case at all?

Comment: We estimate values from data points but extropulating a line.  Frequently the line is not accurate and we see the function is steeper (or less steep) in parts and that to "get back" to the line there it must get less steep (or steeper) than the line and so there must be some point where it is just as steep as the line.  Introducing the "new" difference function is just to make the proof of this easier.

Comment: The Mean Value Theorem can be thought of as saying (in terms of a function that gives position) that there must be an instant in time when your instantaneous velocity is exactly  what your average velocity was. Intuitively it is very clear: if I drive to a city that is 100 miles away, and I do that in one hour, then at some point I must have been going at exactly 100 miles/hr. That is what the Mean Value Theorem tells you.

Comment: There is nothing problematical about having a special case which unlocks the general case for proofs. It happens all the time. Rolle's Theorem is definitely a special case of the Mean Value Theorem, because its hypotheses are the Mean Value Theorem's hypotheses *plus some extra assumptions*, and the conclusion is exactly what the conclusion of the Mean Value Theorem will yield once you add those assumptions. That this special case suffices for the general case does not make it any less a "special case".

Comment: I personally think of the mean value theorem as an application of the intermediate value theorem for derivatives.  As @ArturoMagidin says.  If you travel 100 miles in a hour then if you ever go faster than 100 miles per hour there must be time you are go slower (otherwise it'd take less than an hour) and vice versa.  And if there is a time you are going slower and a time you are going faster there must be some point you are going exactly (before the cop pulls you over for speeding).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Rotation won’t do it, although it’s nice intuition. Rotating the graph of a function need not give you the graph of a function.

Comment: @fleablood Except of course that the derivative need not be continuous, so you can't derive the MVT from the IVT...

Comment: "How does someone come up with this formula in the first place?", well, if we knew how to come up with new ideas and formulas, then science would be pointless and trivial, no? The whole point is that you need this seed of brilliance, that we don't know how to reproduce.

Comment: You can interpret it as follows: the function $f(t)$ measures the distance covered by a car until the moment of time equal $t.$ The distance covered between the momeńts $a$ and $b$ is equal $f(b)-f(a).$ The average speed is equal ${f(b)-f(a)\over b-a}.$ The mean value theorem states that at certain moment the car moved at the speed equal to the average speed.

Comment: @TedShifrin: yes it won't work in all cases, but it does help to get some idea of the link between Rolle and MVT. +1 for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), the MVT was developed as an extension of earlier work such as Rolle's Theorem. In fact, if you check the references for the history section you get [this presentation](https://abesenyei.web.elte.hu/publications/meanvalue.pdf) that even without speaker notes shows a lot of the lead-up to both the statement and proof of the theorem.

On slide 10, Cavalieri's claim from 1635 is essentially the MVT in pre-calculus language:

> If a curved line is situated in one plane and if a straight line meets it in either two points, two line segments, or in a line segment and a point, then we can draw another straight line parallel to the previous line which touches the part of the curve situated between the two mentioned meetings.

Most of what follows that is refining it (including formalising what it means when we're talking about algebraic functions rather than drawing curves on a piece of paper) and various attempts at formally proving it. As for "How do you think of the proof?", unfortunately we can't ask Cauchy how he came up with his particular method, but the correspondence between Peano and Jordan from slide 12 onwards gives a little insight into how these things tend to develop - someone tries something, usually based on previous work, and then a lot of time is spent fixing the problems with it.

Some of it is like lightning - lots of different paths branch out, but you don't actually see anything happen until one of those paths suddenly makes a connection. When you're studying the subject, you usually don't get shown the 100 failed attempts, only the successful one, so it feels like mathematicians just magically think of the perfect way to prove something, but that's very far from the truth.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer! The last para of your answer is what hit me the most. Thank you for the insight.